# Does anybody experience freezing and chrashing of browser while on SE?

Tags: support, bug

I'm using Chrome (Version 29.0.1547.76 m), and lately whether I'm on physics.stackexchange, or on mathematica.stackexchange, when I'm writing a long question, usually with a lot of equations in latex, my browser freezes for a couple of seconds, and crashes.

Luckily I can just go back, and forward and the question is still there, but my title is gone, so I need to put that again.

But still it's kinda annoying.

Do any of you have similar problems?

Comment: Yes, I've experienced this too. But with answers (more content on the page), and the last couple of words die away. I'm also using the same browser, by the way.

Comment: I don't know if it's a browser related issue, or SE related issue :\

Comment: Yes, I have noticed this on IE

Comment: I have noticed it on chrome, too. Questions and answers are often still there but edits (sometimes substantial) are always lost. This used to be common some time ago (no idea how long ago, though) and went away 'magically', but it's come back lately.

Comment: Just a quick note, though. The thing to do in cases like this is to try and see if you can consistently replicate the conditions in which this happened. If you do, write it up and take it to MSO.

Comment: @dingo_d : Same thing for me, with same version of Chrome : 29.0.1547.76 m.